# Make it clearer when looking at a question if I've already voted to close it

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, user-interface

Since "[Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)" we now have the possibility to retract close votes.

However, as mentioned in "[Retracting Close Vote, included in the Vote To Close menu?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245114/retracting-close-vote-included-in-the-vote-to-close-menu)" there is no indication when looking at a question to see if I have already cast such a close vote.

Therefore, could we have a UI improvement to show this? Adding some image with freehand circles to improve visibility.

[image: Cast close vote]

Comment: I'm not clear what your suggested improvement is. Is it a greyed-out background to indicate you can't vote again?

Comment: The example is just an example. The idea is to have "something" to show the difference. I don't really care about what it is as soon as it clearly shows you already voted to close.

Comment: OK, sounds reasonable. A change of text colour (dark red?) is another option I guess.

Comment: Anything the designer might see fit to the UI :)

Comment: The FR doesn't *have to* be applicable to the close button, it could be anywhere.

Comment: Actually this feature actually exists for some time, if you cast a second vote the system tells you that you've already voted. See Astro's answer below.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The author is asking about making it clear "when looking at a question". Solutions that require clicking will not satisfy the request.

Comment: @Sonict 112 views in five years tells me this FR is not in large demand. The system works just fine, there's no need for more bells and whistles.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Plus some more in [this duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321160/377214). (Came across this request as I was about to answer that other one saying it was completed, only to realize it was being provided by a user script. That script's documentation cites this post as the impetus for that behavior.)

Comment: @Sonic a post that was viewed only 72 times.... I needn't say anything else. Please explain why the current system (see below) is unsatisfactory. How it is not useful or not doing its job.

Answer (score 4):

I like this idea, but I don't think it should be anything too conspicuous, because the fact that you've already voted to close something already isn't something that's entirely important (in comparison to the rest of the information on the page) until you've actually opened the dialog.

I'm not sure if this is just a design change, or a functionality change, because whether **you** specifically voted to close the question might not be loaded with the rest of the page and may only load after the dialog has loaded.

---

On the other hand, though, I'm pretty sure it's the former, because that information does appear to be loaded with the rest of the page, as is indicated by the tooltip:

[image: Tooltip]

For that reason, I think it should be simple (and subtle) enough to change the default font color to `#444` (the current hover color for buttons) to indicate that you've already voted to close:

[image: Darker text]

I don't like the idea of changing it to something like dark red or `#888` (the color for disabled buttons) because it indicates that you can no longer perform any actions with that button (which is obviously false).

Comment: CSS hack to implement this: `.close-question-link[title^="You voted to"] { color: #444 }` (Of course, this will not work as is for pt.SO or ja.SO.)