# Highlight "close (x)" when a close vote is already raised

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I always stumble upon questions which are in need of being closed. However, I often forget whether I voted to close a question or not, so I click on "close (x)", wait for the close dialog to load and see whether I've voted or not.

Why not make it clear from the very start? How about highlighting the "close (x)" link when a vote to close is already raised?

No vote raised:

[image]

Vote already raised:

[image]

Comment: If we're on it, the same for the _delete_ links please.

Comment: And for flags too.

Comment: *highlight all the things*

Comment: That might hurt page load performance as it now needs to check if any of the close votes belong to you and that is only beneficial for at most 5 users while all other visitors have to live with the performance penalty. On large sites like SO this will have a negative impact. Let's not do this. It is fixable with a User Script I guess.

Comment: @rene Fair point

Comment: @rene how would a single if statement disrupt the whole page load? Just store the close vote with the user id of the user who raised it. You will loop through the 5 votes only, not through the users.

Comment: Yes, so that is either extra (denormalized)  data or on extra join with the votes table, and yes on a single page view the performance loss is probably not measurable, but I can assure you it adds up given the traffic SO sees.

Comment: Of course it adds up, to the storage significantly but only slightly to the performance.

Comment: If these links are changed, please make sure they're accessible to people with visual impairments.

Comment: @rene at least for the close vote dialog, the mouseover text already includes this information. Such highlighting would therefore be possible without extra queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done purely using CSS:

```css
a.close-question-link[title^="You voted to close"] {
    color: red;
}
```

> [image]

On the one hand the change is simple enough to add to a user style, and on the other hand the change is simple enough that SE can do it - and I'm not convinced that addition of a single CSS rule will have that much of a performance impact.

Comment: _"and I'm not convinced that addition of a single CSS rule will have that much of a performance impact."_ There's no direct information on the question site available, that this particular user voted to close the question, that could be used to control the conditional CSS settings. It would require another request to the server to get this info.

Comment: You do realise that the text I'm checking has already been loaded on to the page? The check has been made anyway, is being made anyway, for you and all users. That's to say, the check already exists and runs right now, only the CSS is left, and the CSS doesn't require any additional request to the server.

Answer (score -1):

As [@rene pointed out in their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321160/highlight-close-x-when-a-close-vote-is-already-raised#comment1052076_321160), this might significantly hurt site load performance, and affect everyone loading the post, no matter if they were involved or not.

That seems to be an unfair trade, regarding having up to 5 users benefit to support their short minded recognition, beyond any others who didn't vote at all yet.

If you try to vote again, the system already informs you well, that you already did so.

Comment: 5 users vote, the others didn't. How is it unfair? Those who didn't vote this time probably would vote another time. Sharing is caring!